# How do I prompt user for input after each round in rock paper scissors?

Tags: javascript

The game works fine after 1 round. I'm trying to play 5 rounds. I tried a for-loop before the while loop. But, it still only prompts the user for input one time.

```
let computerPlay = () => {
      let compChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; //array storing computer possible actions
      let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      let choice = compChoices[i];
    
      return choice;
    };
    
    //
    let playerChoice = prompt("Select your action").toLowerCase();
    let computerChoice = computerPlay();
    
    let playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
      let winner = "";
      if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        winner = "tie";
      } else if (playerSelection > computerSelection) {
        winner = "player";
      } else {
        winner = "computer";
      }
    
      return console.log(winner);
    };
    
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice);
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: After you play the round, call `computerPlay` again (rename it to something else like `round`). This is because the start of `computerPlay` contains the logic you need to restart the round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

As requirement, author is asking to keep `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` params for `playRound`. I'd propose the fix is to put `playerChoice` and `computerChoice` in `while` loop

```
let computerPlay = () => {
      let compChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; //array storing computer possible actions
      let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      let choice = compChoices[i];
    
      return choice;
    };
    
    let playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
      let winner = "";
      if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        winner = "tie";
      } else if (playerSelection > computerSelection) {
        winner = "player";
      } else {
        winner = "computer";
      }
    
      return console.log(winner);
    };
    
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      //here is the change
      let playerChoice = prompt("Select your action").toLowerCase();
      let computerChoice = computerPlay();
      playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice);
      i++;
    }
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Your problem is you pass `prompt` outside of your `playRound`. `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` should be in `playRound` too that would help for resetting values of computer and your choices' every round.

```
let computerPlay = () => {
      let compChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; //array storing computer possible actions
      let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      let choice = compChoices[i];
    
      return choice;
    };
    
    let playRound = () => {
      let playerSelection = prompt("Select your action").toLowerCase();
      let computerSelection = computerPlay();
      let winner = "";
      if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        winner = "tie";
      } else if (playerSelection > computerSelection) {
        winner = "player";
      } else {
        winner = "computer";
      }
    
      return console.log(winner);
    };
    
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      playRound();
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: Assignment instructions were to pass playerSelection and computerSelection as parameters into playRound(). How can I reset after each round doing it that way?

Comment: @medOnline5 you just need to pass `playerChoice` and `computerChoice` in the `while` loop. By the way, I updated my answer too.

Comment: In your answer, would it be possible to pass playerChoice and computerChoice as parameters even though playRound did not specify parameters?